# How can I remove shadow from the md-steppers tag in vue-material?

Tags: vue.js, vue-material

When I create a stepper with vue-material, it automatically adds a class called md-steppers-navigation that adds a box-shadow to each. I would like to remove that, do you know how should I proceed?

Comment: try `.md-steppers-navigation{ box-shadow:none }`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using single file components, in your .vue file where you have `<md-steppers>`, add this block of CSS.

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
    .md-steppers /deep/ .md-steppers-navigation {
        box-shadow: none;
    }
</style>
```

/deep/ here will push the setting down into the steppers component, where the navigation DOM element is created.